# How to write json array to elasticsearch's objetct field by es rest client?

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

I use elasticsearch6.8 and jdk8. The key problem is hot to write json array string to elasticsearch's object type field. Following code show how I tried to write to es.

My mapping is as follows:

```
{
  "mapping": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "c_json": {
          "type": "object"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My c_json value is :

```
{
  "key1": "val1",
  "key2": "val2",
  "key3": "val3"
}
```

My java code is :

```java
String json="{
  "key1": "val1",
  "key2": "val2",
  "key3": "val3"
}";
String keyName="c_json";
Map<String,String> myDataMap = new HashMap();
myDataMap.put(keyName,json);

IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest("my_index").id(esIdValue)
                        .type("_doc")
                        .source(XContentType.JSON,convertMapToEsValues(myDataMap));
            BulkRequest bulkRequest = new BulkRequest();
            BulkResponse bulkResponse = es6Client.bulk(bulkRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

```java
    public static Object[] convertMapToEsValues(Map<String, Object> valueMap) {
        List<Object> kvList = Lists.newArrayList();
        for (String fieldName : valueMap.keySet()) {
            kvList.add(fieldName);
            kvList.add(valueMap.get(fieldName));
        }
        return kvList.toArray();
    }
```

When I run the code, es server give me the exception:

```
  ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=object mapping for [c_json] tried to parse field [c_json] as object, but found a concrete value]],action id is 9, Index name is my_index
```

I check my index doc data in kibana and find c_json contain following values. Is this illgal value cause the exception?

[image]

Comment: This error means that in your index you already indexed documents where the `c_json` is not an object, just a single field, like `c_json = value`. You will need to find and delete those documents or delete your entire index.

Comment: @leandrojmp I have specified the field is an object type. Why the setting not work?

Comment: What is your indexed document? This does not seems to be an json object, but an array with some values. Arrays are not well supported in Kibana.